# Unable to change shutdown event tracker group policy; not on a domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I see [here](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/01/how-to-disable-the-shutdown-event-tracker-in-server-20032008/) how to disable shutdown event tracker for server 2003. I have Windows Server 2003 on a VM. When I open gpedit.msc and I do not see a path for `Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System` as the instructions (and all others I've found) say should be there:

[image: gpedit.msc console doesn't have the needed path]

However, when I click "shut down", the tracker pops up asking for a reason. How can the tracker be turned on but I can't see the policy to edit it?

The computer (a VM) is not on a domain. It is a part of workgroup called "WORKGROUP". I am logged in as "Administrator" user which is in the "Administrator" group.

*At the end of the day, I just want to turn off event tracker*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can the tracker be turned on but I can't see the policy to edit it?

Policy templates just turn options on and off.  They're not what actually launches the shutdown event tracker.  The operating system itself does that without intervention from gpedit.msc, as you've seen.  You don't need policy templates to change configurable aspects of the OS;  you can control Windows update without using the gpedit.msc by editing the registry, for example.

That said...

In gpedit, you should be able to right-click Administrative Templates and select "Add/Remove Templates."  (They live in %SystemRoot%\PolicyDefinitions by default, I believe.)

You can download the default templates from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18664) if they've gone missing.

Comment: Do you know the registry entry for this?

Comment: I had to look, but it's apparently 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability\ShutdownReasonUI' with 1 to enable and 0 to disable.

Comment: I don't have that key/value. In HKLM\Software\microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability I have sub keys (sub "folders") of "Shutdown" and "UserDefined". and In neither `Reliability`, `Shurdown`, or `UserDefined` is there a value with the name "ShutdownReasonUI".

Comment: I also don't have a `PolicyDefinitions` folder anywhere on my system.

Comment: What's weirder is that on my other Win7 machine, the Group policy is there and the registry key is _only_ there when I turn on the tracker. So I don't know why my server2033 machine does not have the registry key but still uses the tracker.

Comment: You might need to download the default templates and add them, like I described above.  Also, it uses the tracker without the registry key because that's the default value.  In Windows 7, the default is to NOT use the tracker.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18664, in case it's lost in the text.